# Javascript/HTML error cannot find variable

Tags: javascript, html

Via onclick I am calling a function that does some calculations and then should be replacing some elements (h1) on the fly with the information calculated within the function.

I have this done the same exact way on several other places on my page, except this one seems to be giving me an error.

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: container2

I believe it might have something to do with the element's ID.

HTML:

```
<div id="macros">
    <h4>Macronutrients recommended:</h4>

    <h2>Protein: <span id="myprotein"></span></h2>
    <h2>Fats:  <span id="myfat"></span></h2>
    <h2>Carbs:  <span id="mycarb"></span></h2>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function calcmacros(bmr){

    var bmrweightvalue = document.getElementsByName('bmr_weight_pounds')[0].value;
    var bmrweight = parseInt(bmrweightvalue, 10);

    var macro_p = (bmrweight*1);

    //window.alert("protein is: " + macro_p);

    var macro_f = (bmrweight*.25);

    //window.alert("Fats are: " + macro_f);

    var macro_c = (bmr - (macro_p * 4 + macro_f * 9))/4;

    //window.alert("carbs are: " + macro_c);

    var contianer2 = document.getElementById("myprotein");
    container2.innerHTML = macro_p;

    var contianer3 = document.getElementById("myfat");
    container3.innerHTML = macro_f;

    var contianer4 = document.getElementById("mycarb");
    container4.innerHTML = macro_c;


}
```

Console:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: container2
calcmacrosrdnSimulator.html:435
onclickrdnSimulator.html:101
```

Line 435 is

```
    var contianer2 = document.getElementById("myprotein");
```

as stated above

Comment: `contianer2 !===== container2 `

Comment: Because you mistyped this variable to `contianer2`.

Comment: Instead of commenting the obvious... vote to close. We don't need typo questions here.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining the container variables as contianer but then referring to them are container.

Change the variables to container and then it should work correctly.

```
var container2 = document.getElementById("myprotein");
container2.innerHTML = macro_p;

var container3 = document.getElementById("myfat");
container3.innerHTML = macro_f;

var container4 = document.getElementById("mycarb");
container4.innerHTML = macro_c;
```

Comment: Syntax error resolved. Thanks guys, once again I am an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a variable that doest exist. Check your syntax...

for example...

var cont**ia**ner2 = document.getElementById("myprotein");
cont**ai**ner2.innerHTML = macro_p;